# Store vars on first run / request

Tags: c#, .net, crm, guid, microsoft-dynamics

I have a CRM application where I need to reference some lookups constantly in the code.  Eg: a certain team in CRM.

The issue is that the Guid's will be different in each environment.

So I am thinking about the first time a call is made to get a certain Guid it will check if the value is `Guid.Empty`.  If so, then go get the Guid.

There is like 20 Guids I need to do this with.

The way I am doing it at the minute is I have a single class file with all the Guids as `Guid.Empty`.

The first time the system goes to get the Guid it will see that it is `Guid.Empty` and so it gets the correct Guid from the database and assigns it.  All subsequent calls to get the same Guid will mean they can get it without calling the database.

But is that the correct / best way?

Comment: Best or correct in terms of what?

Comment: Speed and efficiency, best practice etc.  Does C# have a feature that handles this already that I have missed?  Is it better to include these Guids in an App.config file and use that?  Are there other alternatives?

Comment: If the guids aren't going to change then I would suggest in your app.config is OK. If they're changing frequently then you should be looking at something like caching.

Comment: I agree with Timothy.... Unless we knew the details of your business case what he says makes sense. If you decide you need caching then  c# provides the following class to assist with caching https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx.